# angular service and ng-file-upload by danialfarid

Tags: angularjs

I declared a variable inside a function and modify it again inside another function that is within the variable function. Why the value of variable upload is reset or reinitialize when returning it?

```
var upload = [];

        $upload.upload({

            url: '/ibsapp/app/app/api/libs/upload.php',
            file: file[0],
            data: fileLocation,
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                // add publication data
                AppService.insertService('publication', publication).then(function(response){

                    // If unsuccessful in inserting data in the database, delete the files that are uploaded.
                    if(response['status'] === "error"){

                        $upload.upload({

                            url: '/ibsapp/app/app/api/dbHelper/delete.php',
                            data: fileLocation + '/' + file[0].name,
                        });
                        /* upload value is now the response */
                        upload = response;
                });
            }
        });

        /* When I log here, the value of upload is reset to [] */
        console.log(upload);
        return upload;
```

Comment: you are making an async call right. The console.log(upload); will be printing before the response ever came.

Comment: should i use this return $upload.upload?.... but i can't integrate my data to the $upload.upload. $upload has its own data when its finish and I don't know how to modify it inside the }).success(function())...